# Do I have to redeploy an Azure Web Role to turn on IIS Logging?

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

I have an Azure web role running an MVC Web API site.  I'm using the diagnostics.wadcfg file to configure logging.  So far I've just be using tracing and I view it with the Azure Diagnostics Monitor 2 from Cerebrata/Redgate.  All is well.

I wanted to start logging out IIS requests.  I know I can go to the wad-control-container to do some tweaks to logging by updating the content there as seen here:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ConfigRequest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <DataSources>
    <OverallQuotaInMB>4096</OverallQuotaInMB>
    <Logs>
      <BufferQuotaInMB>1024</BufferQuotaInMB>
      <ScheduledTransferPeriodInMinutes>1</ScheduledTransferPeriodInMinutes>
      <ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter>Verbose</ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter>
    </Logs>
    <DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs>
      <BufferQuotaInMB>0</BufferQuotaInMB>
      <ScheduledTransferPeriodInMinutes>0</ScheduledTransferPeriodInMinutes>
      <ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter>Undefined</ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter>
    </DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs>
    <PerformanceCounters>
      <BufferQuotaInMB>0</BufferQuotaInMB>
      <ScheduledTransferPeriodInMinutes>0</ScheduledTransferPeriodInMinutes>
      <Subscriptions />
    </PerformanceCounters>
    <WindowsEventLog>
      <BufferQuotaInMB>0</BufferQuotaInMB>
      <ScheduledTransferPeriodInMinutes>0</ScheduledTransferPeriodInMinutes>
      <Subscriptions />
      <ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter>Undefined</ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter>
    </WindowsEventLog>
    <Directories>
      <BufferQuotaInMB>0</BufferQuotaInMB>
      <ScheduledTransferPeriodInMinutes>0</ScheduledTransferPeriodInMinutes>
      <Subscriptions />
    </Directories>
  </DataSources>
  <IsDefault>true</IsDefault>
</ConfigRequest>
```

For example I can switch from Verbose to Information log tracing.

Can I turn on the IIS logging from here?  Or do I have to update my diagnostics.wadcfg and redeploy?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Cerebrata's Diagnostic Manager to change the configuration.  It is done instance by instance.  That change will be lost once you redeploy your application or your instance gets reimaged by Azure.

Comment: Is this by adding a subscription first?  I'm trying to do that now.  I created a management cert per these instructions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg551722.aspx and uploaded it via the portal.  Then I'm using the New Subscription Connection dialog.  Unfortunately I'm timing out creating the subscription for some reason.  Just want to see if I'm on the right track with what you suggest.

Comment: Actually, it wasn't a timeout.  I had fiddler open which was messing things up, I assume with the client cert.  Closed fiddler and I was able to configure and see logs once.  I got 3 IIS files.  Then it seems like it stopped working and I've updated it multiple times and it doesn't seem to take.  Not sure if you have any thoughts on that.  Otherwise, thanks for the help.

Comment: Could be allocated space issue.  Azure Diagnostic quotas are very... particular and once they fill up and if they didnt have a chance to get distributed to Azure storage, Diagnostics stop working

Comment: I deleted the table and blob container and rebooted my instances.  I've been assuming it has to do with the quota numbers that I'm not understanding or have wrong.  Any suggested values?  I'm just trying to use Azure Logs (tracing) and IIS Logs.  Would like to copy every minute.

Comment: http://brentdacodemonkey.wordpress.com/2010/08/24/windows-azure-diagnostics-part-2%E2%80%93options-options-options/ Check this page.  If it doesn't help, could you post a new question with a full text of the deployed diagnostics? it may help to figure it out

Comment: thanks but still haven't gotten to work.  posted follow up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537981/why-arent-my-iis-logs-being-copied-for-my-azure-web-role